# angular test not checking the actual value emitted by observable

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am unit testing an observable and checking if it contains a ? element. The source data is as follows.

Though both the expects run without error I am not convinced with the expect that checks for ? mark.

Wouldn't I need to check for the complete element { name: '?', isAlive: false },

When i console.log the result it looks like this

[Object{name: 'Test', isAlive: true}, Object{name: 'Test2', isAlive: false}, Object{name: 'Test3', isAlive: false}, Object{name: 'Test4', isAlive: false}, Object{name: 'Test5', isAlive: false}]

```
export const TestModelObjectMock: any[] = [
    { name: 'Test', isAlive: false },
    { name: 'Test2', isAlive: false },
    { name: 'Test3', isAlive: false },
    { name: '?', isAlive: false },
    { name: 'Test4', isAlive: true },
    { name: 'Test5', isAlive: false }
]; 

const testModelObject = TestModelObjectMock;

   it('should call the title service and filter questionmark', fakeAsync(() => {
        mockTestService.extend({ getTitles: () => of(testModelObject ) });
        setupComponent();
       
        flush();

        expect(component.titleService.getNames().subscribe(result => expect(result).not.toContain('?')));

        
        expect(component.titleNames$.subscribe(result => {expect(result.length).toEqual(5),
        console.log(result)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrapping the subscriptions to the observables into expectations, which you can't.

See here an example how you can test observables:

```js
it('Async test example - RxJS Observables', fakeAsync(() => {
    let test: boolean;

    const test$ = of(test);

    test$.subscribe(() => {
        test = true;
    });

    tick(); // wait for observable to emit

    expect(test).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

Comment: Right but how would I in the subscribe test for it contain   element { name: '?', isAlive: false },

Comment: Like with the test variable. Set a variable inside the subscribe and test it outside - after the tick()